# C++ Function pointer of templated type

Tags: c++, function, pointers, templates

This is probably the most complicated piece of template code I have written.

I have the following using types declared that are templated:

```
    template <class Vertex, class Pixel>
    using VS_TYPE = Pixel(*)(Vertex & v);

    template <class Vertex, class Pixel, class Mesh>
    using VS_THIS_TYPE = Pixel(Mesh::*)(Vertex & v);

    template <class Pixel>
    using PS_TYPE = Vec4(*)(Pixel & sd, const Sampler<Pixel> & sampler);

    template <class Pixel, class Mesh>
    using PS_THIS_TYPE = Vec4(Mesh::*)(Pixel & sd, const Sampler<Pixel> & sampler);
```

They are function pointer types with templated parameters and return values. The ones with 'THIS' are pointers to member functions (of the class Mesh).
I have this templated function declared that takes some parameters of these types:

```
template <class Vertex, class Pixel, class Mesh>
    void DrawElementArray(Mesh* mesh, Vertex* vertices, VS_THIS_TYPE<Vertex, Pixel, Mesh> VertexShader, PS_THIS_TYPE<Pixel, Mesh> PixelShader)
{
      // body of this function
      boundObject = (void*)mesh;
      _DrawElementArray<Vertex, Pixel, Mesh, VS_THIS_TYPE<Vertex, Pixel, Mesh>, PS_THIS_TYPE<Pixel, Mesh>>(..., VertexShader, PixelShader);
}
```

The VertexShader and PixelShader parameters are of these templated function pointer types. Here is the declaration of the _DrawElementArray function:

```
template <class Vertex, class Pixel, class Mesh, typename VSPtr, typename PSPtr>
    void _DrawElementArray(Vertex* vertices, VSPtr VertexShader, PSPtr PixelShader)
{
     // bound object is the Mesh* parameter passed into DrawElementArray
     // There is another DrawElementArray not shown that does not have this parameter, used for passing in Vertex
    // Shader and PixelShader function pointers that are not member functions
     //
     if (boundObject == nullptr) {

           // call vertex shader (parameter unrelated)
           VertexShader(vertices[i3])
     } else {

           // call the member function on the object
           Mesh* mesh = (Mesh*)boundObject;
           (mesh->*VertexShader)(vertices[i1])
     }
}
```

The problem comes when I try to call VertexShader (the function pointer parameter). It gives the following errors:

```
    term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
    ->* : illegal right operand has type VSPtr
```

I am able to call DrawElementArray without seeing any compile errors. Anyone know how to fix these errors? Basically what I am trying to do is write a function (_DrawElementArray) that could take function pointers to either member functions or non member functions

Comment: In your example, `VSPtr` is `VS_THIS_TYPE<Vertex, Pixel, Mesh>` which is a pointer-to-member for the `Mesh` class, so you can't call it as simply `VertexShader(vertices[i3])` since there is no `Mesh` object specified for it. It can only be called like `(mesh->*VertexShader)(vertices[i1])`.  So if the `boundObject` is `nullptr` then you simply can't call `VertexShader` at all.  I think you will have to either overload `_DrawElementArray()` for member shaders and non-member shaders, or else make use of `std::function` for the shaders.

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you. Still getting used to the differences between C++ templates and Java generics.